# Problems with simple bash commands in the shell

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, centos

I need to add java to my PATH on one of my Linux servers, to do this I edited the bashrc and added,

`PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin

export PATH`

Since then I have not been able to use simple bash commands like `ls` `nano` `locate` `cp` is there any way I can fix this? The OS of the server is CentOS 5 with Plesk 9 (64-bit), can anyone help me recover basic functionality in my terminal?

Comment: you cant export and define at the same time `export PATH=...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the java path to your PATH variable, not set PATH to only include the java path

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: ah right, how can I now edit my bashrc without use of nano, pico, vi, vim or similar?

Comment: Sorted it with a bit of SFTP and exporting the bashrc. Many thanks nos

Comment: you could use the full path /usr/bin/nano ...
Most application are in /bin /usr/bin